# Order table results from matching two or more tables

Tags: sql, mysql, match, sql-order-by

I have a `SELECT` statement that gets data from two tables and then dose a `MATCH` somthing like this:

```
SELECT a.*, b.* 
 FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id=b.id 
 WHERE MATCH(a.column) AGAINST( 'somthing' IN BOLLEAN MODE) 
   OR MATCH(b.column) AGAINST( 'somthing' IN BOLLEAN MODE) 
 ORDER BY
```

I want to order the results as so `a AND b BOTH match on the same row` then `a OR b match in a row (order doesn't mater for this)`

any help would be grate!

Comment: what a or b should be true ? that makes no sense as a is a table that can not be true or you mean that matches are bigger than 0?

Comment: @nbk sorry you are right. what I mean is if a match is found for a and b on the same row display it first then all the other matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have the full Text searches not in the select, you need to repeat them.

The rest is a CASE WHEN that determines which come first

```
SELECT a.*, b.* 
 FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id=b.id 
 WHERE MATCH(a.column) AGAINST( 'somthing' IN BOoLEAN MODE) 
   OR MATCH(b.column) AGAINST( 'somthing' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
 ORDER BY 
CASe WHEN MATCH(a.column) AGAINST( 'somthing' IN BOoLEAN MODE) > 0 AND MATCH(b.column) AGAINST( 'somthing' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  > 0 THEN 1
WHEN MATCH(a.column) AGAINST( 'somthing' IN BOoLEAN MODE) > 0 OR MATCH(b.column) AGAINST( 'somthing' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  > 0 THEN 2 END
```

Comment: There's really no reason to be repetitive since it already passed the `where` filter: `CASE WHEN MATCH(a.column) AGAINST('something' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0 AND MATCH(b.column) AGAINST('something' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END`

Comment: we don't know all the criteria so there could be more consider